# XMLHttpRequest handling different requests

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xml, xmlhttprequest

I'm fairly new to `XMLHttpRequest`, and I would like the server to process different requests based on which button a user clicks etc.

I have the `getData()` method set up, but what's the best way of doing this? Do I just have two parameters, one for the data file, and another the `URL/requestBody` so that I can just pass the appropriate variables and data file upon calling the `getData()` method? Is there another way of doing this?

My g`etData()` method currently:

```
var xhr = createRequest();

function getData(dataSource, divID, fName, lName, phone, pickupUnitNumber, pickupStreetNumber, pickupStreetName, pickupSuburb, pickupDate, pickupTime, destinationSuburb, numPassengers, status){
    if(xhr){
        var obj = document.getElementById(divID);
        var requestBody = "fName="+encodeURIComponent(fName)+"&lName="+encodeURIComponent(lName)+"&phone="+encodeURIComponent(phone)+
                                       "&pickupUnitNumber="+encodeURIComponent(pickupUnitNumber)+"&pickupStreetNumber="+encodeURIComponent(pickupStreetNumber)+"&pickupStreetName="+pickupStreetName+
                                       "&pickupSuburb="+encodeURIComponent(pickupSuburb)+"&pickupDate="+encodeURIComponent(pickupDate)+"&pickupTime="+encodeURIComponent(pickupTime)+
                                       "&destinationSuburb="+encodeURIComponent(destinationSuburb)+"&numPassengers="+encodeURIComponent(numPassengers)+"&status="+encodeURIComponent(status);

        xhr.open("POST", dataSource, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

            if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
                obj.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            }
        }

        xhr.send(requestBody);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you clarify where you run into problems? Is your code working?

Comment: Hi, code is working great. What I'm asking is: is there a particular way of getting the getData() method to handle different actions, so like passing different variables etc. to it? So, this code creates a booking and adds it to the database. I then want to have another button that gets all the bookings (obviously using completely different variables), how do I pass that separate request to this same method?

Comment: rather have different methods that do different things!

Comment: It wouldn't let me change the name of the method or add different ones.